# How to display formulas?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations

I am using the following format for all

```
\begin{math}
newP = p + vt + 0.5a(t square)
\end{math}
```

How do I

- from left justified to centrally justified
- leave one blank line before and after the formula
- leave a single space between symbols and
- do this for all formulas at the same time

Comment: `math` is the 'inline' environment, equivalent to `\(` ... `\)` (or `$` ... `$`). You are probably looking for the `equation*` environment, or the shorter `\[` ... `\]` version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A trivial example from which you can learn faster.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The position of a moving particle along the $x$-axis is given by,
\[
x_t = x_0 + vt + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2
\]
where $x_0$ represents the initial position, \ldots.

The speed can be obtained by derivating the position with respect to $t$ as follows,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\textrm{d}x_t}{\textrm{d}t} = v + at
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Remarks:

- Use `\[...\]` or `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` to display an unnumbered equation.
- Use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` to display a numbered equation.
- Use `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` or `\[\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\]` to display multiple rows of unnumbered horizontally-aligned equations.
- Use `\begin{align}...\end{align}` to display multiple rows of numbered horizontally-aligned equations or `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\end{equation}` to display multiple rows of horizontally-aligned equations but only with one equation number.

Answer (score 1):

You need the **amsmath** package for align*, so make sure you have the line `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble (`before \begin{document}`).

```
\begin{align*}
newP = p + vt + 1/2at^2
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Don't use `align*` for a single line equation; prefer `\[...\]` (or `equation*` if `amsmath` has been loaded).